# What does a Python decorator do, and where is its code?

Tags: python, django, decorator, login-required

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Python decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

What does a Python decorator do? And where can I see the codes that are running when I add a decorator to a method?

For example, when I add [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) at the top of a method, does any code replace that line? How exactly does this line check the user session?

Comment: [SO: Mini-guide on decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I add `@login_required` at the top of a method, does any code replace that line?

Kind of. Adding `@login_required` before your view function has the same effect as doing this:

```
def your_view_function(request):
    # Function body

your_view_function = login_required(your_view_function)
```

For explanations of decorators in Python, see:

- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators#What_is_a_Decorator

So decorator functions accept an original function, and return a function that (probably) calls the original function, but does something else too.

In the case of `login_required`, I think it checks the request object passed to view functions to see if the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is in effect a function wrapping another function or class. The function behind the decorator in your case is named `login_required`. Look in your imports to find it.

Comment: No, it's an arbitrary callable manipulating a function or class after the latter's definition. While your version is simpler and captures many common uses, there are also many useful decorators which don't fit that definition.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is a function which wraps another function. Say you have a function f(x) and you have a decorator h(x), the decorator function takes as argument your function f(x) and so in effect what you will have is a new function h(f(x)). It makes for cleaner code as for instance in your login_required, you do not have to put in the same code to test if a user is logged in rather you can wrap the function in a login_required function so that such a function is called only if the user is logged in. Study this snippet below

```
def login_required(restricted_func):
"""Decorator function for restricting access to restricted pages.
Redirects a user to login page if user is not authenticated.
Args:
    a function for returning a restricted page
Returns:
    a function 
"""
def permitted_helper(*args, **kwargs):
    """tests for authentication and then call restricted_func if
    authenticated"""
    if is_authenticated():
        return restricted_func(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        bottle.redirect("/login")
return permitted_helper
```